# Using {{ myvariable }} in Nunjucks just prints "{{ myvariable }}" in final HTML file

Tags: html, templates, nunjucks

I use Metalsmith with Nunjucks in a static site generator. In the project, I am importing a Nunjucks macro into a file and trying to invoke it using {{ someMacro }}. However, in the resulting HTML file, "{{ someMacro }}" gets printed as a string instead of the markup inside the macro.

I've also tried {% set someVariable = "abc" %}, and invoke the variable with {{ someVariable}}, both in the same file, but I get the same issue with "{{ someVariable }}" being printed right into HTML.

I've tried invoking both inside in a {% block xyz%} {% endblock %}. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. In the project I'm working on, we use Metalsmith in-place, and there our engineOptions looks like this:

```
const templateConfig = {
    engineOptions: {
        filters: {},
        tags: {
            variableStart: '<<<',
            variableEnd: '>>>',
        }
    }
};
```

Instead of using {{ }} to use variables or macros, I just had to use <<< >>> to call variables or macros in the main file, and likewise when passing arguments into macros in macro files.